# Vb.net Draw Line Between Two Points

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I want to draw a line between two points:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yuhsd.gif

Lets say that I have **2 panels** and want to draw line from `Panel1` to `Panel2`.

Explanation:

```
dim p1 as new panel
dim p2 as new panel

p1.left = 100
p1.top = 10
me.controls.add(p1)

p2.left = 300
p2.top = 20
me.controls.add(p2)

DrawLineBetween(p1,p2)
```

Comment: Why do you have two panels? Do you want the line to be drawn inside the panels or on the form the panels reside in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like below, it is in c# but you can easily convert it vb.net, and you need to adjust x,y co-ordinates as per the panel position.

```
   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(new Panel{Left = 10, Top = 10,Width = 50,Height = 50, BackColor = Color.Blue});
        this.Controls.Add(new Panel {Left = 100, Top = 100,Width = 50,Height = 50, BackColor = Color.Blue});


    }
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Graphics g;

        g = e.Graphics;

        Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red);
        myPen.Width = 1;

        g.DrawLine(myPen, 12, 12, 45, 65);

        g.DrawLine(myPen, 100, 100, 45, 65);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Graphics.DrawLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1.aspx) method in the `Paint` event of the form.